# Can I use NativeScript-vue with ready-made vue app?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nativescript

If I have a vue app can I use nativescript with it to build a mobile app? 
And Can nativescript build a web app ( responsive ) beside the mobile apps?
Thanks

Comment: This thread gives an idea of feature request with schematics https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/3860

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your second question is YES, The Angular and NativeScript teams teamed up to create nativescript-schematics, a schematic collection that enables you to build both web and mobile apps from a single project.A code-sharing project is one where we keep the code for the web and mobile apps in one place.

I am not an expert in vue so can not answer exactly for your first question, you can read for the same [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/guides/integration-with-existing-ios-and-android-apps/extend-existing-android-app) but if it is an angular project, you can definitely migrate. Read the steps [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/code-sharing/migrating-a-web-project).